# How to use data member of templatized class in typedef

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
struct A {  
    typedef B type;
}


template<>
struct A<double> 
{
    typedef double type;
};


template<typename T, typename U>
B<U> func()
{
   A<U>::type my_type;
   my_type tmp;
}
```

This code does not compile with g++ compiler. error message is :

error: too few template-parameter-lists

Can somebody please explain.

Thanks & Regards,
Van sal

Comment: Probably in the way you call `func`, please add that part of the code.

Comment: What is `B`, used everywhere ?

Comment: Are we to simply *guess* what `B` is in all of this? How about posting *actual* code, including relevant templates/classes?

Comment: You are using `B` once with template arguments and once without. Also, in `A<U>::type my_type;` you are declaring a variable named `my_type`, then proceed to use it as if it's a type name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for the mistakes in question. correct question should be :

```
template <class T>
struct A {  
   typedef B type;
 }


template<>
struct A<double> 
{
   typedef double type;
};


template<typename T, typename U>
void func()
{
  typedef A<U>::type my_type;
   my_type tmp;
}
```

Here basically the problem was that compiler is confused about statement

```
typedef A<U>::type my_type;
```

that whether it is a data member of class or its a type. so we will have to explicitly say that its a type . 
so replace above statement with following statement

```
typdedef typename A<U>::type my_type;
```